# IOS: what type of project to take? ARC or NOT ARC

Tags: ios, route-me, mkstorekit

In my app I'm using the project Route Me Map and this project don't use ARC; at the same time I should use MKSToreKit and its version at 4.0 implement ARC model; 
In this situation what I should to do? 
The best solution that I have in my head is to find an old version of MKStoreKit. 
Do you have other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Go with ARC for your whole app, it is the future and perhaps you wake up one day and find apple stopped non ARC apps.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever use MRC (non-ARC) unless **absolutely** necessary. Xcode is great at converting MRC code to ARC code (Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC...), so just use that and you'll be fine.